# Error when submitting multiple spark applications to standalone cluster

Tags: apache-spark

If I use spark-submit to submit two spark applications, the 2nd application  always fail with error like below.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
```

They all runs fine if I submit them one by one, i.e., wait for the previous application to finish, then submit another one.

What am I missing here? Our cluster uses standalone mode.

Comment: Did you check $SPARK_HOME$/logs for errors?

Comment: @DanielSobrado The error I posted is the only thing I feel might be useful. Apparently there is a collision of some kind between concurrent applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is gone after removing explicitly initializing a SparkContext within the Spark applications. The underlying mechanism still remains a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

You should check a few things -

1. Check if you have used stop() keyword on sparkcontext.
2. Instead you should use:

   sparksession.streams().awaitAnyTermination();
3. Check all running, failed and succeeded jobs on Spark-UI with its log.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know what type of Spark Job you are submitting. If possible add code snippet of your failing Spark application.